# Custom Exchange/Outlook Search

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

We have a custom mail archiving solution and I would like to do a search in Exchange via EWS or Outlook that will search both the Exchange Email store and our Archie solution, effectively combining the two sets of results

I have spend many hours on Google with little luck. If someone can point me in the right direction I can go from there.

Comment: What version of Exchange are you using ?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [EWS Search topics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn579421(v=exchg.150).aspx)?